# Inject sub module to main module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, declaration, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

I want to inject my sub module to main app, but I have injection error

(Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/ng/areq?p0=SelectionCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

it's my main app

[image]

and it's my sub module 
[image]

How can I fix that? Thanks!

Comment: controller should be
`var controllerApp = angular.module('app.newProject', []).controller('SelectionCtrl',function(){ //code here})`

second controller should not create module with dependancy again, it should `controllerApp.controller('TabController1')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are messing up with module declaration. You declared `angular.module('app.newProject')` two times.

While creating it first time you registered `SelectionCtrl`. After that you created another module with same name `angular.module('app.newProject,[]')` with dependancy and registered  `TabController1` controller. When you created second module it overrides first one & now it has only `TabController1` thats why angular is throwing error `SelectionCtrl` is required.

There are several appraoches resolve this approach.

**Approach 1**

Create a module and store it in some variable and use it whenever you want.

```
var controllerApp = angular.module('app.newProject', [])
.controller('SelectionCtrl',function(){ 
    //code here
});

controllerApp.controller('TabController1',function(){
 //your code here
});
```

**Approach 2**

Create a module, and whenever you want to use it, use it without dependency.

```
angular.module('app.newProject', [])
.controller('SelectionCtrl',function(){ 
    //code here
});

angular.module('app.newProject').controller('TabController1',function(){
 //your code here
});
```

**Approach 3** (I wouldn't prefer this approach)

Create a module and append you components in linear manners.

```
angular.module('app.newProject', [])
.controller('SelectionCtrl',function(){ 
    //code here
})
.controller('TabController1',function(){
 //your code here
});
```

I would prefer you to go for Approach 2 which will provide you to bind components any by referring a module.

Comment: yeah,it's working,Thank you very much )))))   And can I ask one more question here?  How can I divide controllers from my app.module.js ? I mean I have to write the controllers in controller js?

Comment: no there is not need to write controller in controller.js, whenever you want to add controller from anywhere you need to just refer that module. as i explained in my answer. Option 2 could provide more flexibility.